# Recursive properties set in Merchello product template's master - Parent must be set in order to recurse

Tags: umbraco7

I have some recursive properties set in the master page of my Umbraco website. These work fine for every page except my product template. I am using the Merchello ecommerce plugin.

On my product pages I get this error:

> Parent must be set in order to recurse

The line of code causing this error is:

```
var pageTitle = Model.Content.GetPropertyValue("seoPageTitle", true);
```

I understand this is due to the product 'pages' not being part of the actual content tree in Umbraco. So somehow I need the product pages to have a parent to get these recursive properties working.

If I'm right with this, how do I set a parent?

Thanks very much in advance.